# Automount with autofs, encfs and keyring access

Tags: automounting, autofs, encfs

I have build myself a nice setup:

I have encrypted encfs folders that are mountable with autofs, i.e. when I enter the folders they will be automatically decrypted. I have the encfs password added to my keyring and wrote a custom script that extracts the password (`/usr/local/sbin/load-encfs` see below).

The only drawback is that I have to enter my login password to unlock the keyring on the first visit of any of the automounted folders. Every visit of another folder (or the same after the timeout expired) does not prompt me for my pw.

**Question:** Is there any possibility that also the first password prompt can be somehow automated?

---

`/etc/autofs/auto.master`:

I just added this line:

```
/-  /etc/autofs/auto.encfs
```

---

`/etc/autofs/auto.encfs`:

```
/home/user/Privat -fstype=fuse  :load-encfs\#user\:/home/user/encfs-keys/private.xml\:/home/user/Dropbox/.private
/home/user/BTU -fstype=fuse :load-encfs\#user\:/home/user/encfs-keys/btu.xml\:/home/user/Dropbox/.btu
/home/user/TUD -fstype=fuse :load-encfs\#user\:/home/user/encfs-keys/tud.xml\:/home/user/Dropbox/.tud
```

---

`/usr/local/sbin/load-encfs` (fish script):

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

function usage
    echo "need at least two arguments"
    echo "  1. <user name>:[<config>]:<crypt folder>"
    echo "  2. <mount folder>"
    exit 1
end

if test (count $argv) -lt 2
    usage
end

set split (string split ':' $argv[1])
if test $status -ne 0
    usage
else if test (count $split) -eq 2
    set USER_NAME $split[1]
    set CONFIG_PATH ""
    set CRYPT_PATH (realpath $split[2])
else
    set USER_NAME $split[1]
    set CONFIG_PATH (realpath $split[2])
    set CRYPT_PATH (realpath $split[3])
end

set MOUNT_PATH (realpath $argv[2])

set PID (ps aux | sed -e '/sed/d;/$USER_NAME.*xinit/!d;s/^.*xserverrc \(:[0-9\.]*\).*/aaa/' | awk '{ print $2 }')
if test -n "$PID"
    set DISPLAY (cat /proc/$PID/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | grep '^DISPLAY=' | sed -r 's/.*=(.*)/\1/')
end
if test -z "$DISPLAY"
    set DISPLAY ":0.0"
end

set PASS (env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY sudo -H -u $USER_NAME secret-tool lookup server $CRYPT_PATH)

if test -n $CONFIG_PATH
    set COMMAND "env ENCFS6_CONFIG=$CONFIG_PATH"
end

set COMMAND $COMMAND "encfs --public --extpass='echo \'$PASS\'' $CRYPT_PATH $MOUNT_PATH"
eval $COMMAND
```

I added the various arguments to be flexible where the config file for encfs is stored.

Comment: Obviously the simplest approach would be to extract all passwords from the keyring to plain files like [here](http://scrupp.de/2012/07/automounting-encfs-using-fstab/) but I don't want to store it in plaintext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution after having problems with dbus after an update. New script:

```fish
#!/usr/bin/fish

function usage
    echo "need at least two arguments"
    echo "  1. <user name>:[<config>]:<crypt folder>"
    echo "  2. <mount folder>"
    exit 1
end

if test (count $argv) -lt 2
    usage
end

set split (string split ':' $argv[1])
if test $status -ne 0
    usage
else if test (count $split) -eq 2
    set USER_NAME $split[1]
    set CONFIG_PATH ""
    set CRYPT_PATH (realpath $split[2])
else
    set USER_NAME $split[1]
    set CONFIG_PATH (realpath $split[2])
    set CRYPT_PATH (realpath $split[3])
end

set MOUNT_PATH (realpath $argv[2])

set PASS (sudo -H -u $USER_NAME bash -c "env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/`id -u $USER_NAME`/bus secret-tool lookup server $CRYPT_PATH")

if test -n $CONFIG_PATH
    set COMMAND "env ENCFS6_CONFIG=$CONFIG_PATH"
end

set COMMAND $COMMAND "encfs --public --extpass='echo \'$PASS\'' $CRYPT_PATH $MOUNT_PATH"
eval $COMMAND
```